# j2objc eclipse plugin is not working

Tags: j2objc

I am trying to use the J2objC plugin to convert a working java project. I have downloaded the latest version of the plugin and am using Eclipse Juno. I've got J2objC 0.8 on my machine. I have set an output path and have tried a few different settings within the plug-in.  However, no files of any kind are written/copied/exported anywhere when I run the plug-in.  The console reads as follows:
J2OBJC Conole

Source Directory: /Users/name/Desktop/folder/Workspace/projectfolder
Destination Directory: /Users/name/Desktop/folder/translatedjava/projectfolder
Export finished.

Answer (score 0):

Install the j2Objc plugin for eclipse from marketplace,

You need to download the latest version (https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases) zip file and extract it, then go to eclipse -> Preferences -> j2Objc -> Set path to compiler -> Extracted path of downloaded zip.

Ref:

Check here,

[J2Objc Translator not generating files in Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542129/j2objc-translator-not-generating-files-in-eclipse-luna?rq=1)