# J2Objc Translator not generating files in Eclipse Luna

Tags: objective-c, eclipse, macos, eclipse-luna, j2objc

I am using Eclipse Luna in Mac of version 10.10. I tried installing J2Objc plugin from Eclipse Market Place. The following are the configurations to J2Objc preference, properties, Output folder and Output. But the files are not generated in respective directory. Kindly prefer a solution.

**J2Objc preference**
[image: preferences] 
**Properties**
[image: properties]
**Output folder**
[image: Output folder]
**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27227721/2670892 Sounds like there may be a problem with the plugin so you may need to contact the plugin author. Also remember that everyone here is a volunteer, asking for solutions ASAP is likely to annoy people.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution:

J2Objc in Eclipse Market place installs the master package. Referencing it's root in **j2Objc Preference(1st image)** fails generating Objective c files. I have dowloaded the latest release of plugin [here](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases) and referenced it in **J2Objc Preference** and hence the source code translated in output folder. Thank you everybody.